# Unable to boot installed Ubuntu on 2006 Mac Pro (1,1)

Tags: boot, mac, grub-efi

Added bootia32.efi to install USB Stick and can boot to try/install. Install goes smoothly but am unable to boot the installed version (20.04). I've tried the usual suspects (reinstall grub, boot-repair, grub rescue solutions) nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Do not know Mac, but saved a couple of links for more info, now older? Installed Lubuntu 18.04 LTS on a MacBook Air 1,1 (early 2008) 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2402179
Old Mac with core2duo & 32 bit UEFI
https://mattgadient.com/2016/07/11/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/

Comment: Resetting "system management controller" SMC. PRAM, or NVRAM, is a good idea.